# Determine linear mapping matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Determine the matrix $F$ in ${\rm I\!R}^3$ that is defined by first projecting $u$ on the plane through origo with the normal $(1,2,1)\times(1,0,1)$ and then the picture of $P(u)$ gets projected  on $P(u)\times v$ where $v=(1,1,1)$. (Assume ON-base)

So here is how I thought to solve it:

First, let $N=(1,2,1)\times(1,0,1)=(2,0,-2)$ we can then use the projection formula to see what happens with our base-vector $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$.

So $$e_{1//N}=\frac{e_1\cdot N}{|N|^2}\cdot N=\frac{2}{16}(2,0,-2)$$
$$e_{2//N}=\frac{e_2\cdot N}{|N|^2}\cdot N=0\cdot(2,0,-2)$$
$$e_{2//N}=\frac{e_3\cdot N}{|N|^2}\cdot N=\frac{-2}{16}(2,0,-2)$$
This is the part where I'm note completly sure, my thought is that this gives us the matrix $$P(u)=(e_{1//N},e_{2//N},e_{3//N})$$
From here I'm not quite sure how to proceed. My thought is to multiply $u\cdot P(u)$ and we will get, let's call it $w$ and then $w\times v$. But since we are looking for the matrix $F$ this can't be the right approach.

Looking for some guidance in how to approach these kinds of problems,

Many thanks,

Comment: If $e_1=(1,0,0)$ and $N=(2,0,-2)$ then the component of $e_1$ in the direction of N is $(\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{1}{2})$ and the component projected onto the plane is $e_1$ minus this vector, or $(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: For second part, I guess you work out $e_j\times v$, for $j = 1,2,3$ and find the matrix which implements cross multiplication by $v$. Your composite transformation is then the product of your two matrix transformation (in the right order).

Comment: @Paul, thank you for the guidance, highly appreciated!

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding the description of the second transformation. $P(u)\times v$ is orthogonal to $P(u)$ for all $u$, so isn’t the result of this sequence of projections identically zero?

Comment: I am not sure what "projected on $P(u)\times v$" means exactly. The mapping $T(x) = x\times v$ is a linear mapping and so must have a matrix. We can find this matrix by calculating the $T(e_j)$. T is not a projection but I cannot think of any other interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Paul I'm sorry for the confusion around the question as it's an direct translation of swedish I might have used wrong terminology. But the suggestion you made earlier seems to be the right approach, can't say for sure but It seems like it! Thank you for taking your time!